# QT C++ QPainter - How to appropriately use 'this'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a `QPainter` object. 
All the examples do something similar. But it complains:

> X:\Folder\ink.cpp:56: error: C2664: QPainter::QPainter(QPaintDevice *) : cannot convert parameter 1 from Ink *const to QPaintDevice *
>   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Simplified Code:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPainter>

class Ink
{
public:
    void ink::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* event )
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
    }
};
```

The error occurs on line: `QPainter painter(this);`

Then it also complains

> X:\Folder\ink.cpp:11: error: C2653: ink : is not a class or namespace name

which is on line:

```
void ink::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
```

Please use baby words, I only started with C++ today.

Comment: If you "started with C++ today" I think you shouldn't jump straight to Qt stuff, you have to learn the basis of the language first. This true for any language, but doubly true for C++, since it's particularly complicated as a language.

Comment: I was trying to avoid saying that, but I was thinking it.

Comment: You guys are probably right, when the project starts to feel futile I always take ten steps back.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The constructor for `QPainter` seems to take a pointer to a `QPaintDevice`, and you're trying to pass it a pointer to an `Ink` instance, so it won't work. Perhaps you meant to derive `Ink` from `QPaintDevice`, in which case you'd want `class Ink : public QPaintDevice { ...` etc.
2. You don't need the `ink::` when you're defining a function inside a class. `Ink` and `ink` are, in any case, not the same thing, since C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to be the right direction but now I am getting `inkpuppet.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl InkPuppet::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@InkPuppet@@MEAAXPEAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)`

Comment: I have no idea what `InkPuppet` might be.

Comment: thats the name of the project

Comment: Not in that context. It's looking for a class.

Comment: I see now. That's just UI code, nothing to do with what I'm doing and it's automatically generated by QT Creator, the error mustn't even be indicative of what the actual problem is.

Comment: Something in inkpuppet.obj is trying to call that function, but the linker can't find it.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem,  it was code I inserted elsewhere while experimenting.